# How to pass and use model in Dotliquid ViewEngine

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, viewengine, dotliquid

In my MVC web-application project I'm using [Dotliquid.ViewEngine](https://web.archive.org/web/20151126040100/http://www.theoutfield.co.uk:80/blog/tag/dotliquid) to automatically render my view as it said in the related blog post.I have a class inherited from "Drop" like this

```
 public class FakeProduct : Drop
{
    public string Name { set; get; }
}
```

and fill the model very simply in controller just like below

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = Entities.Product.Where(p => p.ObjectId == 1173).ToList().Select(p => new Models.FakeProduct() { 
        Name= p.Name
        }).SingleOrDefault();
        return View(model);
    }
```

Model is filled correctly ,So I pass it to view as usual, just like it was mentioned in blog post. and rename the view extension to .liquid
This is the view code

```
 @model PooyaSoft.PooyaShop.Web.Website.Models.FakeProduct
    <ul id="products">
    <li> 
        @Model.Name
        <h2>{{ product.Name }}</h2>
        <h2>{{ Name }}</h2>
        <h2>{{ FakeProduct.Name }}</h2>
        <h2>sample product</h2>
    </li>
</ul>
```

but none of the liquid tags shows any output. I m sure that I m using my viewmodel in a wrong way. but I didn't found any answer.Thanks if any one show me a sample or give me a clue.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `RubyNamingConvention` (which is the default), then try this:

```
{{ model.name }}
```